# Generate a range of numbers using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to generate a range of numbers with a fixed interval. I need to display them exactly as shown below.

Starting from 1 and end at 200, the interval is 50.

Two numbers in each row, a space between numbers, arranged this way...

```
1 50
51 100
101 150
151 200
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using bash:

```
for (( i = 1; i < 200; i += 50 )); do echo $i $(( $i+49 )); done
```

`$(( ))` is for arithmetic expansion.

`for (( ; ; ))` is the compound command that resemble the C `for` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
#!/bin/bash

start=$1
end=$2
step=$3

while [ $start -le $end ]
do
  echo  $start $(( start + step-1 ))
  (( start+=step ))
done
```

Start, end and step values are passed as positionnal parameters.

Comment: With this approach, the last range contains a value over the end limit.

Answer (score 1):

Works in **sh**:

```
#!/bin/sh

step=0

for i in $(seq 4); do
    step=$(($step+50))
    echo $(($step-50+1)) $step
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate two sequences with brace expansion, replace spaces with newlines and then paste the results together:

```
$ paste <(echo {1..151..50} | tr ' ' $'\n') <(echo {50..200..50} | tr ' ' $'\n')
1   50
51  100
101 150
151 200
```